# Java class for script parameters

Tags: java, groovy

I'm working on a Java motor for Groovy.
I want to make a class that can stock all the parameters needed to execute my Groovy script.

What is the best way to stock those parameters, I thought to make a list of list that could contain "Type", "Name" and "Value" but I think I'm on the wrong way ?

I searched but I haven't maybe that is too basic.

Comment: Not quite sure what you need. Can you post what you already have and how that's not working?

Comment: I have a class that contain a map<String, String> the 1st is the name of the parameter, the second is the value.

Comment: Basicly You're trying to create ScriptContext ;) and it's better to have Map as a container of those properties.